# Asp.Net Identity: invalid_request on redirect when calling REST function GetExternalLogin

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-identity

This error applies to the **Single Page Application** template when selecting the **ASP.NET Web Application** project in Visual Studio. Add a valid Facebook appId and appSec to the Startup.Auth.cs file to test the demo with external login.

I am able to login into Facebook but only if the redirect url which is defined in **app.datamodel.js** in the js variable siteUrl is set to '/' . As expected, when the call is made to the **GetExternalLogin** REST function inside the **AccountController** the user is sent to the Facebook page to do the external login. If I put a breakpoint inside the GetExternalLogin it is triggered as well.

However, if I change the siteUrl in the **app.datamodel.js** to anything else e.g. '/dummyController' the breakpoint is not triggered at all, instead the response gives the message **error: invalid_request**

Any idea why this does not work?
Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To set a valid redirect url I had to set it inside the ValidateClientRedirectUri inside the ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs file

Comment: @ShawnMclean Here's a great sample project I'm following. Doorman is probably talking about something like the following:

https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.API/Controllers/AccountController.cs#L276

Comment: Thanks, thats what I've been following too.

Comment: For code you can refer Link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26276646/1129978